# In machine learning(Linear Regression), in the training/test process I got this Type Error. Can someone help me with that?

Tags: python, machine-learning, linear-regression, sklearn-pandas

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder, OneHotEncoder
labelencoder = LabelEncoder()
X[:, 3] = labelencoder.fit_transform(X[:, 3])

onehotencoder = OneHotEncoder(categorical_features = [3])
X = onehotencoder.fit_transform(X).toarray()
print(X)
```

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-33-723c0ae23eaf> in <module>
      3 X[:, 3] = labelencoder.fit_transform(X[:, 3])
      4 
----> 5 onehotencoder = OneHotEncoder(categorical_features = [3])
      6 X = onehotencoder.fit_transform(X).toarray()
      7 print(X)

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py in inner_f(*args, **kwargs)
     70                           FutureWarning)
     71         kwargs.update({k: arg for k, arg in zip(sig.parameters, args)})
---> 72         return f(**kwargs)
     73     return inner_f
     74 

TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'categorical_features'
```

​

​

Comment: The error indicates that `categorical_features` is not a valid parameter to pass to `OneHotEncoder` as you are.

Answer (score 0):

The argument should be `categories` according to [sklearn docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html).